# gcc: cannot execute 'cc1plus'

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I have just downloaded the C++ compiler MinGW, checked everything in the MinGW Installation Manager, and put the \bin location. But when I test the compiler in one of my C++ compilers, I get the following error:

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I would appreciate it if I would get an idea on how to fix the compiler!

Comment: Bad installation probably.... Did you consider using some *recent* Linux distribution, like [Debian](https://debian.org/) ?

Comment: What does 'put the \bin location' mean? Have you added the bin location to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes, I put the C:\MinGW\bin location in my PATH environment variables.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I got the download from the official MinGW website. http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: @anonymous I don't have an explanation for your error but FYI my installation of MinGW does not include cpp1plus and I have no trouble compiling C++ files.

Comment: BTW [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). **You are allowed to** download the source code *and then* improve it, that is to **fix the compiler**, and that might be easier on a computer running [Debian](https://debian.org/) - which you could install on your computer in less than an hour

Comment: Check also your [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install gcc-c++ or g++, and then set the environment variable.
You can also run `g++ -v` to check whether g++ was installed correctly or not.

Comment: Like I said I already put the location in the environment variable, but the error still occured.

Comment: Did you run the command 'g++ -v' ? What was the output?

Comment: It said "g++ is not recognized as an internal command".

Comment: So, I think the cause of the problem is that g++ was not installed or g++ was installed incorrectly or the environment variable was set incorrectly.